# Django get_absolute_url is redirecting to random blog posts

Tags: django

I've created a website with a blog, and I'm trying to redirect the user to the previous blog post after sending a comment. However, it redirects to random blog posts rather than the previous one.

Models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title and self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Views.py:

```
class CommentView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `self.post_id` for the primary key of the post, otherwise you redirect to the post that "happens" to have the same primary key as the primary key of the comment,so:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post_id})
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.